# How to fix this type error thrown by regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to collect all the internal links of Requests library for python and filter out all the external links.

I am using regular expression to do the same. But it is throwing this type error that I am unable to solve.

My code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

r = requests.get('https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/')
content = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
[i['href'] for i in content.find_all('a') if not re.match("http", i)]
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b7d82067fe9c> in <module>
----> 1 [i['href'] for i in content.find_all('a') if not re.match("http", i)]

<ipython-input-10-b7d82067fe9c> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 [i['href'] for i in content.find_all('a') if not re.match("http", i)]

~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in match(pattern, string, flags)
    171     """Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    172     a Match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 173     return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
    174 
    175 def fullmatch(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing it a BeautifulSoup node object not a string. Try this:

```py
[i['href'] for i in content.find_all('a') if not re.match("http", i['href'])]
```

Comment: `re.match("http", i['href'])` is better written as `i['href'].startswith("http")`

Comment: Both solution works! Thanks for explaining where I went wrong @Robert