# Trying to Scrape multiple URLS from one page

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

**I am trying to scrape the info from the election results in 18 NI constituencies here:**

http://www.eoni.org.uk/Elections/Election-results-and-statistics/Election-results-and-statistics-2003-onwards/Elections-2019/UK-Parliamentary-Election-2019-Results

Each of the unique URLs starts like this:

```
http://www.eoni.org.uk/Elections/Election-results-and-statistics/Election-results-and-statistics-2003-onwards/Elections-2019/
```

The selector for the 18 URLS is as follows:

```
#container > div.two-column-content.clearfix > div > div.right-column.cms > div > ul > li
```

What I want to start with is a *list with the 18 URLS*. This list should be clean (i.e. just have the actual addresses, no tags, etc)

My Code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.eoni.org.uk/Elections/Election-results-and-statistics/Election-results-and-statistics-2003-onwards/Elections-2019/UK-Parliamentary-Election-2019-Results'

response = requests.get(url)
response.status_code

text = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, parser="html5lib")

link_list = []
for a in soup('a'):
    if a.has_attr('href'):
        link_list.append(a)

re_pattern = r"^/Elections/Election-results-and-statistics/Election-results-and-statistics-2003-onwards/Elections-2019/"
```

**This is where I get lost, as I need to search for all 18 URLS that start with that pattern (The pattern is wrong I am pretty sure. Please help!)**

The rest of the code:

```
import re
good_urls = [url for url in link_list if re.match(re_pattern, url)]
```

here I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-f3fbbd3199b1> in <module>
----> 1 good_urls = [url for url in link_list if re.match(re_pattern, url)]

<ipython-input-36-f3fbbd3199b1> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 good_urls = [url for url in link_list if re.match(re_pattern, url)]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py in match(pattern, string, flags)
    173     """Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    174     a Match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 175     return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
    176 
    177 def fullmatch(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

What should I type differently to get those 18 urls?  Thank you!

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417684/how-to-fix-this-type-error-thrown-by-regular-expression-in-python

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't help... different application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the job.

I've removed some unnecessary imports and stuff that's not needed here, just readd them if you need them elsewhere of course.

The error message was due to triyng to do a regex comparison on a soup object, it needs to be cast to string (same problem as discussed in the link @Huzefa posted, so that was definitely relevant).

Fixing that still left the issue of trying to isolate the correct strings. I've simplified the regex for matching, then use a simple string split on " and selecting the second object resulting from the split (which is our url)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
url = 'http://www.eoni.org.uk/Elections/Election-results-and-statistics/Election-results-and-statistics-2003-onwards/Elections-2019/UK-Parliamentary-Election-2019-Results'
response = requests.get(url)
text = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
re_pattern = "<a href=\".*/Elections-2019/.*"
link_list = []
for a in soup('a'):
    if a.has_attr('href') and re.match(re_pattern, str(a)):
        link_list.append((str(a).split('"')[1]))
```

Hope it fits your purpose, ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply earlier, but thanks for the solution! Very neat!

Comment: @chefbilby Excellent, glad to hear! Don't forget to mark my answer as an accepted answer to help others find the solution.

Comment: Just did that! Thanks again!