# How to scrape a link from a multipart email in python

Tags: python, regex, email, gmail-imap, imaplib

I have a program which logs on to a specified gmail account and gets all the emails in a selected inbox that were sent from an email that you input at runtime.

I would like to be able to grab all the links from each email and append them to a list so that i can then filter out the ones i don't need before outputting them to another file. I was using a regex to do this which requires me to convert the payload to a string. The problem is that the regex i am using doesn't work for findall(), it only works when i use search() (I am not too familiar with regexes). I was wondering if there was a better way to extract all links from an email that doesn't involve me messing around with regexes?

My code currently looks like this:

```py
print(f'[{Mail.timestamp}] Scanning inbox')
sys.stdout.write(Style.RESET)
self.search_mail_status, self.amount_matching_criteria = self.login_session.search(Mail.CHARSET,search_criteria)

if self.amount_matching_criteria == 0 or self.amount_matching_criteria == '0':
    print(f'[{Mail.timestamp}] No mails from that email address could be found...')
    Mail.enter_to_continue()
    import main
    main.main_wrapper()
else:
    pattern = '(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)'
    prog = re.compile(pattern)

    self.amount_matching_criteria = self.amount_matching_criteria[0]
    self.amount_matching_criteria_str = str(self.amount_matching_criteria)
    num_mails = re.search(r"\d.+",self.amount_matching_criteria_str)
    num_mails = ((num_mails.group())[:-1]).split(' ')

    sys.stdout.write(Style.GREEN)
    print(f'[{Mail.timestamp}] Status code of {self.search_mail_status}')
    sys.stdout.write(Style.RESET)
    sys.stdout.write(Style.YELLOW)
    print(f'[{Mail.timestamp}] Found {len(num_mails)} emails')
    sys.stdout.write(Style.RESET)
    num_mails = self.amount_matching_criteria.split()
    for message_num in num_mails:
        individual_response_code, individual_response_data = self.login_session.fetch(message_num, '(RFC822)')
        message = email.message_from_bytes(individual_response_data[0][1])
        if message.is_multipart():
            print('multipart')

            multipart_payload = message.get_payload()
            for sub_message in multipart_payload:
                string_payload = str(sub_message.get_payload())
                print(prog.search(string_payload).group("url"))
```

Comment: If these messages have html parts, and the urls are in anchor tags you could use Beautiful Soup (or some other HTML parser) to get them.

Comment: they are in anchor tags, i'll look at using bs4

Comment: This question and answer from yesterday may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65262687/trying-to-scrape-multiple-urls-from-one-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this for loop with a recursive function and a regex to get the links, i then removed all links without a the substring that you can input earlier on in the program before appending to a set

```
for message_num in self.amount_matching_criteria.split():
    counter += 1
    _, self.individual_response_data = self.login_session.fetch(message_num, '(RFC822)')
    self.raw = email.message_from_bytes(self.individual_response_data[0][1])
    raw = self.raw
    self.scraped_email_value = email.message_from_bytes(Mail.scrape_email(raw))
    self.scraped_email_value = str(self.scraped_email_value)
    self.returned_links = prog.findall(self.scraped_email_value)
                  
    for i in self.returned_links:
    if self.substring_filter in i:
        self.link_set.add(i)
    self.timestamp = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    print(f'[{self.timestamp}] Links scraped: [{counter}/{len(num_mails)}]')
```

The function used:

```
def scrape_email(raw):
        
    if raw.is_multipart():
        return Mail.scrape_email(raw.get_payload(0))
    else:
        return raw.get_payload(None,True)
```